# Angular Bootstrap: How to show no results found message in typeahead textbox results

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

Have textboxes and typeahead functionality, I'm able search if data is available with typeahead, is there any way to show for unmatched records like "No Results Found" in typeahead pipe itself. Could you please share your suggestions. Please find attached reference screenshot of "No Results Found" message.

[image]

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngb-typeahead-blut-not-updatoing-9hsytc?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
  public search = (text$: Observable<string>) => {
    return text$.pipe(
      debounceTime(200),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      map(term => {
        if (term.length < 2) {
          return [];
        }
        const searchResults = states
          .filter(v => v.toLowerCase().indexOf(term.toLowerCase()) > -1)
          .slice(0, 10);
        return searchResults.length > 0 ? searchResults : ["No Results found"];
      })
    );
  };
```

Comment: This is a not a solution and is quite a common bug actually (working with strings for logic). Nothing stops the user from selecting the empty option, and "No Results found" could also be a completely valid option.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to achieve this

Check this out. i have updated the example

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngb-typeahead-blut-not-updatoing-way-1?file=app/typeahead-basic.html

This way, The No Results Found Text can be added down to your input box.

If that is also not required, add a layer of div tag and toggle it if there are no proper results found.

[image: Sample No Results Found in DIV]

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngb-typeahead-blut-not-updatoing-way-2?file=app/typeahead-basic.html

Comment: This will just add another data "No Result Found" to the array.

Comment: This is not a solution. Adding "No results" to the array is a bad idea. Something should distinguish a real result from "No results" and it can't be the value of the string.

Answer (score 0):

Much better if you just add another element underneath the input.

> <span *ngIf="isNoResult">No Results Found.

Use the output **typeaheadNoResults**  assign the value to isNoResult variable

***typeaheadNoResults*** − fired on every key event and returns true in case of matches are not detected.

In Your ts:

> typeaheadNoResult(e){
> this.isNoResult = e;   }